# I need some references about the leanback of android tv

Tags: android, android-tv, cardview

here's the deal .... i'm working on the leanback of android tv ,i need to place an icon in the left side of my card the problem is the app  only use the  style from the leanback theme,the xml only accept 16 dp  , and if i try to change that the file auto delete this sooo my question is , there is a way to make change on those files? because i need something like this:

[image]

here is my code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {

    LiveTv card = (LiveTv) item;

    final ImageCardView cardView = (ImageCardView) viewHolder.view;


    if (card.getCardImageURI() != null) {
        if(card.getTipo()==0){
            cardView.setMainImageDimensions(CARD_WIDTH,CARD_HEIGHT);
            cardView.setTitleText(card.getNombre());
            Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext()).load(card.getCardImageUrl()).error(mDefaultCardImage).into(cardView.getMainImageView());


        }else {
            Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext()).load(card.getLogo()).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(CARD_WIDTH,CARD_HEIGHT) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resource);

                    cardView.setBadgeImage(drawable);

                }
            });

            cardView.setMainImageDimensions(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
            cardView.setTitleText(card.getChannel() + "   " + card.getNombre());
            cardView.setContentText(card.getTsStart() + " " + card.getTsEnded());
            Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext()).load(card.getCardImageUrl()).centerCrop().error(mDefaultCardImage).into(cardView.getMainImageView());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "f i try to change that the file auto delete this" please clarify your wording. who deletes what?

Comment: android studio autodelete my changes , the file that i want  to change  show a layer "Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited"  is there anyway to change those files?

Comment: YOu cannot change a build file as those are generated by the build process generally.

Comment: already did it , in a forum of leanbacks  they told me to override the badge style and with that my problem was solve... thx anyways :D

Comment: now i have a new problem... i'm trying to place an image in  above of the main image .... i'm not sure if its possible.

Comment: Try to create new SO ticket for your new problem, so that other people in this community can check that new problem.